# Mysql Unix Timestamp Store?

Tags: php, mysql

I got a bit of a problem here. My database stores unix timestamps as a string `2011-09-01 20:22:36` and I need it as a Unix Timestamp ########### so I can compare it using a > then symbol. But I also need to have it automatically set the timestamp on update (`ON UPDATE CURRENT TIMESTAMP`) as well as have a `default of the timestamp` **which is not really that important cause I can do that in PHP if I need to.**

How can I do this? `timestamp` is now a date/time combo string and not a integre so I cannot compare it?

My comparison string is

`$sql = sprintf("SELECT nid, field_date_value, field_movie_location_value FROM content_type_mobile_event WHERE updated<'%s'", $vid);`

Incase anyone is wondering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) to convert it inside your query. If you must compare it to a Unix timestamp from PHP, it is easiest to allow MySQL to handle the column's conversion on its end.

```
$sql = sprintf("SELECT nid, othercols FROM content_type_mobile_event WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(updated) < '%s'", $vid);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can compare DATETIME columns with operators like > or <, so I don't see what the problem is. For example, you can do this :

```
SELECT *
  FROM table
 WHERE your_column > NOW() - INTERVAL 2 HOUR;
```

If you *really* need unix timestamps (you shouldn't, it's a bad habit PHP users have), you can use the function `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` :

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(your_col)
  FROM table;
```

You can also use FROM_UNIXTIME to convert a unix timestamp to a valid date :

```
SELECT *
  FROM table
 WHERE your_column > FROM_UNIXTIME($data)
```

This is what I would use if I *really* had to use a unix timestamp, but most of the time, you can do without.

Comment: Yes but NOW() is a mysql function to generate exactly what MySql is looking for then subtract 2 hours. I have a UNIX timestamp integre string that I need to compare to a string and it is not working.

Comment: Steven: You don't have to use NOW(), it was only an example. You can use dates in many ways, I suggest you to read the docs. I also edited my post to tell you about `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` and I'll make a second edit to talk about `FROM_UNIXTIME`.